# Identify visit from robot

Tags: php, ip, web-crawler, referer

In my site, whenever there is a visit I send a cookie and then I save datas in db (data, ip, referer, platform). The cookie is used for avoid of recording the same user visit.
My question is simple: how can I identify visit from robot? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read [User Agent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if( preg_match('/robot|spider|crawler|curl|^$/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) )
{ 
    echo 'Is bot or spider or crawler or curl or not human';
}
else
{
    echo 'Is human';
}
```

You can find a list of about 300 common user-agents given by bots here: http://www.robotstxt.org/db.html